# Using units and piecewise functions in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, units, piecewise

For simple cases, Quantities appear to be handled well by `Integrate`:

```
m = Quantity["Meters"];
s = Quantity["Seconds"];

Integrate[1 m/s, {t, 1 s, 2 s}]
```

returns `1 m`.

But `Integrate` has problems when `Piecewise` is introduced:

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{1 m/s, 1 s <= t < 1.5 s}, {2 m/s, 1.5 s <= t <= 2 s}}], {t, 1 s, 2 s}]
```

returns:

```
Integrate::units: Integrate was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input.
```

I've tried rearranging the units in a few different ways. For example:

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{1 m/s, 1 <= t/s < 1.5}, {2 m/s, 1.5 <= t/s <= 2}}], {t, 1 s, 2 s}]

Integrate[Piecewise[{{1, 1 <= t/s < 1.5}, {2, 1.5 <= t/s <= 2}}] m/s, {t, 1 s, 2 s}]
```

But everything I've tried so far gives the same error.

I am aware I could completely remove the units from the integration and tack them back on afterwords, like this:

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{1, 1 <= t < 1.5}, {2, 1.5 <= t <= 2}}], {t, 1, 2}] m
```

However, that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to make this work?

**Update**

Thanks to @zentient, whose answer led me to the solution I finally used, which is this:

I globally define my unit symbols like this:

```
m = Quantity["Meters"];
s = Quantity["Seconds"];
```

… so I couldn't use @zentient's solution directly.  However, by wrapping `Integrate` in a `Block`, I can achieve the same effect.  I also found that it worked better to assume that my unit symbols were greater than zero.  This eliminates the piecewise result given by @zentient's approach.

```
Block[{m, s}, Integrate[Piecewise[{{1 m/s, 1 s <= t < 1.5 s}, {2 m/s, 1.5 s <= t <= 2 s}}], {t, 1 s, 2 s}, Assumptions -> {m > 0, s > 0}]]
```

This returns `1.5 m`.

The `Block` temporarily undefines the unit symbols, so that they are treated as generic symbols within the `Block`. Upon exiting the `Block`, the unit symbols are automatically replaced with their global definitions.

(I'm sure there's a more technically precise way to explain that using DownValues and whatnot, but I don't quite grok all of that yet!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the following approach is acceptable.

Define a list of rules for the quantities

```
myrules = {
  m -> Quantity["Meters"],
  s -> Quantity["Seconds"]
}
```

Then carry out the integration, using the [Assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html?q=Assumptions&lang=en) option to overcome Integrate's objections and applying the rules afterwards with [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll&lang=en) (a.k.a. " /. ").

```
Integrate[
  Piecewise[{{1 m/s, 1 s <= t < 1.5 s}, {2 m/s, 1.5 s <= t <= 2 s}}],
  {t, 1 s, 2 s}, 
  Assumptions -> {t ∈ Reals, s ∈ Reals}
] /. myrules
```

This integration gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This answer led me to the solution I finally used.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Integrate[
 Piecewise[{{1* m/s, 1 *s <= t < 1.5* s}, {2* m/s, 
    1.5* s <= t <= 2 *s}}], {t, 1*s, 2*s}, 
 Assumptions -> {m > 0, s > 0}]

(*   1.5 m   *)
```

The trick here is that I do not use the Quantity staff. I never do. Here m and s are variables, just like t. Important is that m and s should be declared positive (through the Assumptions in Integrate). Anyway it is faster than tinkering around with Quantity.
Have fun